# PHP Dropdown with start time and end time

Tags: php, time

I'm currently making a booking form for a restaurant, but they have different opening hours. I have a little example how I imagined it would be.

I'm from Denmark, so it's not 10am and 10pm, but 10:00 and 22:00.

```
<?php

    // Opens at 10:00
    $mondayStart = "10";

    // Closes at 22:00
    $mondayEnd = "22";

?>

<select>
    // Here it is gonna generate times from 10:00 to 22:00 with 15 minutes apart like:
    // <option>10:00</option>
    // <option>10:15</option>
    // <option>10:30</option>
    // etc.
</select>
```

I really hope someone could help me. A tutorial or a video could also help alot.

Comment: I believe standard `for` loops will be able to help you here.

Comment: for x=10 to 22 do { for y=0 to 59 do { print x+':'+y; y+=15; } }, something like that with a bit fixes and check for "zero first" 00.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code:

```
<select>
<?php
$start_hour = 10;
$end_hour = 22;
$minutes_array = array("15", "30", "45");
for($i=$start_hour; $i<($end_hour + 1); $i++){
    $string = $i . ':00';
    echo '<option value="' . $string . '">' . $string . '</option>';
    if($i != $end_hour){
        for($j=0; $j<sizeof($minutes_array); $j++){
             $string = $i . ':' . $minutes_array[$j];
             echo '<option value="' . $string . '">' . $string . '</option>';
        }
    }
}
?>
</select>
```

Here's a different solution:
you'll be using one loop, but you'll have to write the array by yourself.

```
<select>
<?php
$hours_array = array("10:00", "10:15", "10:30", "10:45", "11:00", "11:15", "11:30", "11:45", "12:00", "12:15", "12:30", "12:45", "13:00", "13:15", "13:30", "13:45", "14:00", "14:15", "14:30", "14:45", "15:00", "15:15", "15:30", "15:45", "16:00", "16:15", "16:30", "16:45", "17:00", "17:15", "17:30", "17:45", "18:00", "18:15", "18:30", "18:45", "19:00", "19:15", "19:30", "19:45", "20:00", "20:15", "20:30", "20:45", "21:00", "21:15", "21:30", "21:45", "22:00");
for($i=0; $i<sizeof($hours_array); $i++){
    echo '<option value="' . $i. '">' . $i . '</option>';
}
?>
</select>
```

Comment: This is working just perfect! Thank you so much. You just made my day!

Comment: Thanks :) I'll be glad if you can up-vote the answer so that others benefit

Comment: Sorry, I can't up-vote yet. I just joined this week. I only have 8 reputation :(

Answer (score 5):

You could use the [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function for this.
Try the following code, it should give you what you want.

```
 $time_start = '10:00';
 $time_end   = '22:00';

 # use date function with the time variables to create a timestamp to use in the while loop
 $timestamp_start = strtotime(date('d-m-Y').' '.$time_start);
 $timestamp_end   = strtotime(date('d-m-Y').' '.$time_end);

 # create array to fill with the options
 $options_array = array();

 # loop through until the end timestamp is reached
 while($timestamp_start <= $timestamp_end){
     $options_array[] = date('H:i', $timestamp_start);
     $timestamp_start = $timestamp_start+900; //Adds 15 minutes     
 }

 //Do with the options array as you wish
 print_r($options_array);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<select>
    <?php 
        $tNow = strtotime('10:00');
        $end_time = strtotime('20:00');
        while($tNow <= $end_time){
            $optionvalue = date("H:i",$tNow);
            echo '<option value="'.$optionvalue 
              .'">'.$optionvalue.'</option>';
            $tNow = strtotime('+15 minutes',$tNow);
        }
    ?>
    </select>
```

or you can use timepicker

```js
$('#time_at').timepicker({
     'timeFormat': 'H:i',
     'step': '15',  //15 Minute
     'minTime': '10:00',
     'maxTime': '22:00',
     'showDuration': true
});
```

```html
<!-- Css Link -->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-timepicker/1.10.0/jquery.timepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!-- js Link-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-timepicker/1.10.0/jquery.timepicker.js"></script>

<label>Time</label>
<input id="time_at" type="text" placeholder="HH:MM (Duration)">
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Slugonamission right. You could create an array to store the booking times and then incorporate a `for` loop to loop through the array and increment what ever amount is needed. Hope this helps man